# Datamapper "Model.all()" method creates 3 selects and not selecting the right fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sinatra, padrino, ruby-datamapper

I've started to use Datamapper with Padrino and i have some weird issue.
The issues is explained below:

1.The code:

```
 content_type :json
 @fonts = Font.all(:fields=>[:id,:name,:class_name])
 @fonts.to_json
```

2. Datamapper executes 3 queries and return me the all result with all fields.

Please see the sql queries that executed:

DEBUG -  (0.000087) SELECT `id`, `name`, `class_name` FROM `fonts` ORDER BY `id`

DEBUG -  (0.000205) SELECT `id`, `post_script_name`, `designer`, `license`, `category`, `full_name`, `style`, `weight`, `filename`, `copyright`, `system_file_path`, `http_path`, `ext` FROM `fonts` ORDER BY `id`

DEBUG -  (0.000158) SELECT `id`, `font_face` FROM `fonts` ORDER BY `id`

Please help me with that
Why it's happening ?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Ok, i've found that dm-serializer causes to that problem with to_json method.
Any thoughts how to fix this the right way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is:

```
 content_type :json
 fields_to_select = [:id,:name,:class_name]
 @fonts = Font.all(:fields => fields_to_select).to_json(:only=> fields_to_select)
 @fonts
```